# How to remove duplicates in query for google big query by a subset of returned rows, and keep first?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, distinct-on

In pandas, I can drop duplicates by a subset of columns and keep first by

`df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['column1', 'column6'], keep='first')`

I am trying to figure out how to do the same in a query for Google big query.

I saw that GROUP BY is what is recommended for such a case, so I tried something like

```
query = """
SELECT
table1.column1,
table1.column2,
table1.column3,
table2.column4,
table2.column5,
table3.column6,
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON
(
table1.columnA = table2.columnA
AND
table1.columnB = table2.columnB
AND
table1.columnC = table2.columnC
)
JOIN table3
ON
table3.column6 = table2.column6
GROUP BY
table1.column1
table3.column6
"""
```

I get an error like

`select list expression references tableX.columnY which is neither grouped nor aggregraed at [4:5]`

It seems that since I have multiple other column values when I group by the columns I want to GROUP BY, I get an error. After some more googling, I saw that I should use DISTINCT ON to keep the first of the multiple values for my GROUP BY. So then I tried

```
query = """
SELECT DISTINCT ON (table1.column1, table3.column6)
table3.column6
table1.column1,
table1.column2,
table1.column3,
table2.column4,
table2.column5,
table3.column6,
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON
(
table1.columnA = table2.columnA
AND
table1.columnB = table2.columnB
AND
table1.columnC = table2.columnC
)
JOIN table3
ON
table3.column6 = table2.column6
"""
```

But I am now getting an error that says something like

`400 syntax error, unexpected keyword ON at`

From searching, it seems that Google Bigquery does not use DISTINCT ON. But the only solution I can find is to use GROUP BY, which already is not working.

So in a query, how can I drop duplicates for a subset of columns, and drop rows where grouping by that subset has multiple values for other columns.

A solution that de-duplicates based on a subset after a query won't work for me, since my issue is the query without deduplication takes a long time to finish due to the large number of rows returned.

Comment: `keep='first'` in Pandas is not supported in BigQuery. You can de-duplicate a table using a window function like`ROW_NUMBER()` in BigQuery but you have to specify which row will be the first by sorting the table using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 Did the above suggestion help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jaytiger has mentioned in the comments, we have to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function coupled with `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Consider the query below. I have tested the query on sample data and have compared the results with that of a pandas snippet.

```
SELECT * from
(
  SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column6 ORDER BY columnX) row_num
FROM
  `<project-id>.test_dataset.keep_first_in_duplicate`
)
where row_num=1
```

The usage of the `ORDER BY` clause depends on the requirement, the requirement being order preservation of the input data. Unlike a pandas dataframe, the order of input data is not preserved in BigQuery. If we wish to preserve the order, we have to have a new column with indices that can be used to sort the data after ingesting into BigQuery. In summary, if your data source follows a certain order, there will be differences between the deduplication output from BigQuery and that of the pandas dataframe.